# Did I properly grade the ground around my house?

Tags: concrete, walls

I had some water issues in my basement recently.  Taking a good look at all the possible causes I noticed the landscaping around the front my house was slopping in towards the house.  So to fix this I dug up approximately 2 feet of black dirt from the front and replaced it with clay that was slopped at a more appropriate angle.  I then put landscape fabric down and covered that with approximately 4-6 inches of 1/2" washed drainage rock. I also added a 6 inch strip of brick in front of the rock.

So far I have had no problems with water in the basement although I have noticed the concrete on the front of the house looks wet.  What could be causing this? Did I miss a step or 2?

Comment: is it always wet or only when it rains?

Comment: Does "concrete on the front of the house" mean the foundation wall? Or do you have a concrete pad next to the house? Or something else?